# Joomla component "attachments" allow html in input

Tags: joomla, components, attachment, strip-tags

this question might be a bit special. I am using this Joomla 2.5 extensions to give authors the abilty to add Attachments to articles: [Joomla Attachments](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/3115)

The extension renders an input field called "description" in a backend form to insert an file description for the provided file. Unfortunately it´s not taking HTML tags which I need. By saving the form it seems a strip_tags() or preg_replace() or something similar cleans the input. I combed through the code of the attachments extension but couldn´t find a place where the input is cleaned or saved.

To hopefully stay in the Question + Answer rule of Stackoverflow:

Is there a class which extensions inherit from the Joomla Core to save form data to a DB-table ( which also could be responsible to clean and validate user input )?

thanks for any idea,

tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see how the field is defined first:

**1. Form definition**

look into the

```
administrator/component/yourcomponent/models/forms/somename.xml
```

there you could find a form definition, if so it will also specify the field type: depending on the type there are several available filters; for example the default textarea will strip html, and you need to set

```
filter="raw"
```

in order to enable it. see http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_and_parameter_types for a list of fields, click and you can find the available format options.

**2. model**

If the model inherits from JModelAdmin or JModelForm or other JModel* it will automatically handle binding of the forms' data to the database, look for the Save function which should receive the form $data.

**3. more**
There are at least another dozen possibilities. If the above didn't help, try finding the form: possibly you could find it just by looking at the markup.  Once you have the form, check the following fields:

- option
- task
- view

This should help you find the php code that is invoked based on the form:

- if view is set, maybe in ./views/someview/view.html.php you could find the saving logic.
- if task is set, look for a function with the same name in ./controller.php
- if task contains a ".", look for the controller in the ./controllers/ folder.
- if option is not the name of your component, your component is sending the data to another component for saving, and most likely set a return-url

Comment: Hi Riccardo, thanks for your detailed answer. The Form definition filter="" does not to change anything, but I found two things. The Form has hidden input fields with Option and Task: <input type="hidden" value="com_attachments" name="option">
<input type="hidden" value="attachment.edit" name="task"> and the controller (controller/params.php) seems to fetch data from the form with: $data = JRequest::getVar('jform', array(), 'post', 'array', JREQUEST_ALLOWHTML); I thought I could add the JREQUEST_ALLOWHTML to it, unfortunately this also doesn´t change anything? any idea about these two things?

Comment: YES YES YES! Found it thanks! The Controller binds the Formdata, by adding allow raw it works if (!$attachment->bind(JRequest::get('post', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW))